# Edit Summary for multiple edits

Tags: feature-request, edits, edit-summary

When editing a question multiple times within a specific time frame, the edits are combined to a single edit in the history page (which is good) - however, I just noticed that also only the **most recent Edit Summary** is shown.

In https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26502478/revisions, I made two edits with an Edit Summary like

- First edit: "fixed indent"
- Second edit: "removed stray undefined characters"

but the history page only shows "removed stray undefined characters" for the combined edit, which is only half of the truth.

Should the summary of a combined edit not show the Edit summary of **all** the single edits? Otherwise, the Edit summary might be confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you edit again within the grace period, the edit summary is still filled in. So simply don't clear it, just append to it.

With your suggestion, it would be impossible to correct a mistake in the edit summary.

Comment: Thanks - good point about "append to the default summary"